# Exception java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError android/app/Activity

Tags: java, android, eclipse, exception

In an android app, having:

```
public class Pars extends Activity{
    public Document docout(){

          InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.talechap01);
        Document docout = null;

         DocumentBuilderFactory domFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
          DocumentBuilder builder = null;
        try {
            builder = domFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            docout = builder.parse(is);

        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return docout;
    }
```

and

```
public class Manager {

    public static String getStory(String spage, Document docs) {

          XPathExpression expr;
          XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();

           Object result = null;
           String num = spage;
           String par = null;

           try {

           expr = xpath.compile("//decision"+num+"/p//text()");

            result = expr.evaluate(docs, XPathConstants.NODESET);
          }

         catch (XPathExpressionException e) {

             e.printStackTrace();
          }

          NodeList nodes = (NodeList) result;

         for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {

           par = nodes.item(i).getNodeValue();

           System.out.println(par);
         }
         return par;
      }
}
```

Now I want to test the code.

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {Pars p = new Pars();
        Document doc = p.docout();
        System.out.println(Manager.getStory("000", doc));
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I run "Test" as a java application and I get:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   android/app/Activity  at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native
>   Method)   at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)   at
>   com.stack.over.Test.main(Test.java:11) Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.app.Activity    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)   ... 13 more

I tried to find how to fix it but cannot achieve it.
I have this answer from another question but I'm kind of noob yet and can't figure it out how to fix it.

> You have defined your Pars class as extending the class Activity. The
>   error you are seeing is telling you that the class
>   android.app.Activity is not available on the classpath. Maybe you need
>   to check which libraries you import. –  adamretter Mar 5 at 10:01

Thanks all.

Answer (score 3):

The error is that you're trying to run a program that references Android classes (`android.app.Activity`) as a regular Java program that doesn't have Android runtime libraries in its classpath.

You should run Android apps as Android apps (on an emulator or a device) and regular Java programs as regular Java programs and not mix the two. `Activity` is Android; `main()` method is regular Java.

To learn Android app development, you can start with the [developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com) [getting started documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

The error message says it all.  You are writing Android now.  Trying to write a main method doesn't make any more sense in Android than it would if you were writing a webapp that runs in Tomcat.  You are going to need to step back and read up on how Android works.

Comment: Actually, it's a trivial case of clicking the wrong choice from the run dropdown.

Comment: Uhh... not it isn't:  public class Pars extends Activity... Pars p = new Pars()...  That won't work.

Comment: If the poster is actually trying to create a testing framework for Android code outside of Android, then they are going to have to provide their own implementation of numerous Android classes such as `Activity`.  If they are simply trying to do Android development, they clicked the wrong run choice and the `Test` class exists only as a mistaken attempt to work around the problems resulting from that mistake.

Comment: Yes, it is certainly true that they clicked the wrong run choice